# Picking Non-duplicate Random Numbers using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, duplicates, numbers

How would I pick 5 random lottery numbers without having duplicate numbers? The code below is what I have so far and I just can't figure out where to insert the code to loop through to pick out duplicate numbers and reassign new numbers? I've tried adding if and else along with forEach function but it didn't work. This is the code I have so far. Thank you in advance.

```
let lotto = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      lotto[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 69) + 1;
    }

const sorting = lotto.sort((a,b) => a - b);
    console.log(sorting);
```

Comment: For that use case, I'd create an array with all numbers, shuffle it (e.g. using the Fisher-Yates algorithm) and pick the first elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Create a list of your numbers, then pick (and remove) 5 from them.
2. Create a loop that keeps generating numbers until it has 5 unique ones.

Your attempt can be adapted for solution 2:

```js
let lotto = [];
while(lotto.length < 5) {
    console.log('Got', lotto.length, 'numbers!');
    // Changed 69 to 5 to "force" clashes (well, make it very likely)
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    if (!lotto.includes(num)) lotto.push(num);
}

const sorting = lotto.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(sorting);
```

Comment: While certainly slower, you could also just nest for loops to generate a number and then compare it to each number already stored in `lotto`;

Comment: @OnionSoap isn't that basically what my `.includes` does? While it's not an explicit loop, it is actually iterating over the array, checking whether the element is already present.

Comment: Is that the checkmark under the arrow buttons? Sorry I am kind of new here

Answer (score 2):

Considering the process will run at leats one time, the best solution is to use a do while loop and verify if this number already exist in the list.

```
const lotto = [];

do {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 69) + 1;
    if(!lotto.includes(random)) lotto.push(random);
} while(lotto.length < 5);

const sorting = lotto.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(sorting);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will study this as well.